# trying to scrape a flash video off of a news site

Tags: flash, screen-scraping

How should I go about scraping this flash video off of this site - http://www.wmur.com/chronicle/28559748/detail.html - i've tried everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RealPlayer (http://www.real.com/realplayer/search) lets you download flash videos from anywhere online.

Once you hover over the video, a box should pop up saying "Download to RealPlayer." After download, you can even convert the file to another filetype.